# How to place comments in the beginning of the line in list?

Tags: python

I would like to create a big list of strings:

```
biggie = \
[
    "text1",
    ...
    "text10000",
]
```

that list is created from a lot of premade data (for example lines from some programs output). During test creation, I have an error that item number `n` is broken, so I would like to write something like this.

```
biggie = \
[
    1 "text1",
      ...
    n "textn",
      ...
    10000 "text10000",
]
```

to know which item it actually is (EDIT: during code inspection in the text editor, not during runtime) and on what position. I would like to write these preceeding numbers as comments, but when I write something like this:

```
biggie = \
[
    """1""" "text1",
            ...
    """n""" "textn",
            ...
    """10000""" "text10000",
]
```

Python just appends these two string together. How to create such comment? Yes, it is important to me to have it on the same line.

Kind Regards

Comment: Python doesn't have inline comments `/* in this style */`, so you can't have a comment followed by actual code on the same line. How important is it that the comment appears to the _left_ of the string? If ordering doesn't matter, you could do `"textn", #n`

Comment: You can't; why does the number have to precede the list entry?

Comment: Are you looking for ``enumerate`` perhaps?

Comment: I wanted to have an option to place a number before the list element in the text editor. The performance impact is not an issue, as this number placement is only a temporary solution. I also wanted to have the text itself 'enumerated' instead of the result, as it made the navigation easier. I had a lot of messy strings, I had to compare two sets of messy data. I knew the difference is at line `n` but I couldn't find it in the text editor easily :)

Comment: Do you use an editor that has line numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hack, but it takes advantage of the fact that a `dict` preserves the insertion order of its keys as of Python 3.7.

```
biggie = list({
    1: "text1",
    2: "text2",
    ...,
    10000: "text10000",
}.values())
```

(Syntactically, this is a bit lighter than, say, a list of tuples.)

I would seriously consider instead using

```
biggie = [
    "text1",  # 1
    ...,
    "text10000",  # 10000
]
```

Comment: This answer satisfies me, as this comment is a temporary solution anyway :) Thank you!
BTW - comments at the ends of the line are not an option for me, as I had many strings ranging from very short to very long ones, so I wouldn't have the numbering organized into one column easily.